# Why Bref cannot load bootstrap: "Error: Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [/var/task/bootstrap /opt/bootstrap]"?

Tags: php, lambda, serverless, bref

I am investigating on how I can create an AWS lambda in php using the [bref](https://bref.sh/) library

Therefore, according to [documentation](https://bref.sh/docs/installation.html) I set up the environment with the following command cocktail:

```
sudo -H npm install -g serverless
composer require bref/bref
```

Then using the following command created my first php lambda:

```
 vendor/bin/bref init
```

And I selected the first option `PHP Function` provided by default. Creating the following creating an `index.php` file:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

lambda(function ($event) {
    return 'Hello ' . ($event['name'] ?? 'world');
});
```

Then I changed my `serverless.yml` into that:

```
service: app

provider:
    name: aws
    region: eu-central-1
    runtime: provided
    stage: ${opt:stage,'local'}

package:
    exclude:
        - '.gitignore'

plugins:
    - ./vendor/bref/bref

functions:
    dummy:
        handler: index.php
        name: Dummy-${self:provider.stage}
        description: 'Dummy Lambda'
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-73}
```

And I try to launch it via the following command:

```
sls invoke local --stage=local --docker --function dummy
```

But I get the following error:

```
{"errorType":"exitError","errorMessage":"RequestId: 6403ebee-13b6-179f-78cb-41cb2f517460 Error: Couldn't find valid bootstrap(s): [/var/task/bootstrap /opt/bootstrap]"}
```

Therefore, I want to ask why I am unable to run my lambda localy?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is getting a lot of views, I recommend to have a look at the Bref documentation:

**[Local development for PHP functions](https://bref.sh/docs/function/local-development.html)**

That involves using the `bref local` CLI command instead of `serverless invoke local`:

```sh
$ vendor/bin/bref local hello
Hello world

# With JSON event data
$ vendor/bin/bref local hello '{"name": "Jane"}'
Hello Jane

# With JSON in a file
$ vendor/bin/bref local hello --file=event.json
Hello Jane
```

Answer (score 0):

On my local, clearing cache before invoking lambda worked fine, I'm using linux / ubuntu

```
docker system prune --all
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf ~/.cache/
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a known [bug](https://github.com/brefphp/bref/issues/409) for bref. It can be solved via providing the layer manually on  your function in `serverless.yml`. So the `functions` section at serverless.yml should change from:

```
functions:
    dummy:
        handler: index.php
        name: Dummy-${self:provider.stage}
        description: 'Dummy Lambda'
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-73}
```

Into:

```
functions:
    dummy:
        handler: index.php
        name: Dummy-${self:provider.stage}
        description: 'Dummy Lambda'
        layers:
            - 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:209497400698:layer:php-73:15'
```

The reason why is that `${bref:layer.php-73}` cannot be resolved into a php layer. Therefore, you need to provide manually the arn for the lambda layer.

Keep in mind that the arn comes into various "versions" that is being inidcated from the last number in the arn seperated with `:`. So in the arn

```
arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:209497400698:layer:php-73:15
```

Indicated that the layer is in version "15" whitch is thje latest at the moment of the answer. The next one logically should be the:

```
arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:209497400698:layer:php-73:16
```

Comment: If anyone's looking for the bref AWS runtimes, they are documented here: [https://runtimes.bref.sh/](https://runtimes.bref.sh/).